# In which 3GPP specification is UPF defined?

Tags: 5g

Most of the 5G network functions have dedicated specifications but I could not find any specification specific to UPF. Why is that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The N4 interface uses PFCF which is specified in 3GPP TS 29.244 Interface between the Control Plane and the User Plane Nodes.